# Adobe Premiere Pro Preview Not Playing Full Speed

Tags: premiere, adobe

I know the question's been asked a million times. I've read and tried most solutions and haven't received a fix. I come from working on a Mac in Final Cut X, cutting a 30 minute TV show every week. I took the same footage over to Premiere CC 2015.3 on Windows and even just trying to play back a single clip with no effects the video preview lags behind the audio.

Just trying to play back a 1080p H.264 MPEG4 AVC QuickTime Video, 29.97 FPS. None of the following worked: Tried reducing playback quality to 1/4. Ensured the sequence settings matched my video settings. Rendered from in to out. Uninstalled the application and installed it again on my SSD alongside my OS. The footage is being played back from a separate internal HDD.

I really doubt it's a hardware problem because I'm running a 6700K @ 4.4GHz OC, 16GB DDR4 2400 RAM, Nvidia Gigabyte G1 Gaming 1070 card w/ up to date drivers.

EDIT: To start my project I'm creating new project with Mercury GPU (CUDA) renderer. Then rather than deal with settings I drop my main clip into the timeline and it auto detects the footage incorrectly, setting the FPS to 10fps. Changing this back to 29.97 does nothing. Even rendering it all out after this change doesn't change anything.

EDIT 2: Went and looked up the Premiere Pro CC course on Lynda, downloaded that project and media. Everything works great. So where's the issue? In my project settings or with the media?

Any final ideas? A NOOB guide on setting up the project and sequence in case I'm missing something? Thanks so much for your help. If I can't solve it in a week, I'll be asking for a refund from Adobe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Corrupted Media**

I'd bet you've got a problem with your media.

The hint is that Premier Pro auto-detects it at 10fps.

Premier Pro is broadcast production ready, so it's unlikely the cause.

You could try ffmpeg to give you an idea of what's wrong.

`ffmpeg -v error -i file.avi -f null - 2>error.log`

That will give you a log file of errors.

see https://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-file-avi-mpeg-mp4

**2. Cache**

Another thought is there may be cached media previews that are broken. So clean the media cache database and move it off your boot disk.

**3. Overclocking**

I don't like overclocking a system until I know it's stable. That could be a problem there.

**4. Windows version**

You don't mention which version of Windows you're running (7-10?) I don't know anyone running production systems on 10. But that's not a lot of people.

Comment: Tried ffmpeg on my linux rig, didn't provide any useful errors. I do think however it is something to do with the file. The reason for my confusion is simply because these files were from a show that I completed 2 weeks ago in Final Cut X with no problems. Might try a different method of capture if I want to edit in Premiere. It goes from cam over SDI to a BlackMagic Mini Recorder. Will update answer if I can find the cause of the problem. Thanks.

Comment: That workflow should be rock solid, so it shouldn't be all the media files, just a couple. Have you checked the BlackMagic forums?